# Tag location with its type (mountain, lake, beach and so on)

Tags: python, geolocation, geospatial

I encountered a difficulty in tagging location with its type. (I mean mountain, lake, beach and so on)
[please click here to see the screenshot of my data, it doesn't allow me to show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tEt4.jpg)

The geo info I have are longitude/latitude and country code/city/postcode. I'm wondering how can I tag them with the nearest geographic object (mountain, lake...)?

Thank you, guys!

Comment: This question is far too broad. What dataset are you using? What API? Does it contain geographic object information? Please show some actual data, code etc for us to help you.

Comment: Thank you for giving advice! I'll update my questions.

Comment: It looks like you'll need to find a dataset that contains topological features and coordinate data.